# Automated Test Framework in Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-hrsd

I want to use Automated test framework to test if required set of plugins and their versions are correctly installed in my `ServiceNow` instance, and I am not sure of the next steps to take.

I am also not entirely sure if I have to use scripting for the `ATF` plugin tests.

I have Created a New test and impersonated a user.

Comment: After much effort and research, I was able to deduce that a manual test using Excel sheet would be quite useful. Hence for these kind of tests, it is advisable to use Excel sheet and simply follow through the steps one would have employed for automation.